# Generating periodic structure using RegionPlot3D

Tags: graphics, regions

I am trying to create a periodic structure from a unit cell figure which I created using `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 0.6, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

While I can create multiple instances of the unit figure using something like

```
RegionPlot3D[
   x^2+y^2+z^2 || 
   (x-1)^2+y^2+z^2 ||
   x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2 <0.6, {x,-0.5,0.5}, {y,-0.5,0.5}, {z,-0.5,0.5}
]
```

I would prefer to have something like a parameter which I can vary to get the multiple instances. Just as an example, I want something like

```
Graphics3D[
      Table[
         Sphere[{x,y,z},0.6], {x,0,2,1}, {y,0,2,1}, {z,0,2,1}
      ]
 ]
```

but with my unit figure. Is it possible to achieve it using `RegionPlot3D`? I am perfectly happy with any other solution - even one which might generate the unit cell with something else. Thanks.

Comment: The region you define is a sphere, but with your plot ranges you have a cutoff sphere, is that what you are going for?

Comment: Exactly. My unit cell is a cut-off sphere, and I want to create a periodic structure using multiple instances of that unit cell.

Answer (score 4):

One useful function for generating periodic structures is `Mod[]`. Consider the following:

```
RegionPlot3D[Mod[x, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[y, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[z, 2, -1]^2 < 1,
             {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
             PlotPoints -> 95, PlotStyle -> Opacity[3/4]]
```

[image: a cell]

---

One can fiddle a bit with the scaling so that the spheres intersect instead of just touching. Consider the following:

```
RegionPlot3D[Mod[2 x, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[2 y, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[2 z, 2, -1]^2 < 12/5,
             {x, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]}, {y, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]},
             {z, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
             PlotStyle -> Opacity[3/4]]
```

[image: clustered spheres]

To get the interstices, just negate the region function:

```
RegionPlot3D[! (Mod[2 x, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[2 y, 2, -1]^2 + Mod[2 z, 2, -1]^2 < 12/5),
             {x, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]}, {y, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]},
             {z, -2 Sqrt[3/5], 2 Sqrt[3/5]}, PlotPoints -> 95]
```

[image: interstices]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `Mod[]` function. I took your code and tried to fiddle around with it. But I couldn't get it to generate the cut-off spheres I want.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. I will try to understand the Mod function.

Answer (score 3):

What I'd try to do would be to create a region object and use `TransformRegion[region,TranslationTransform[...]]` to create a displaced copy of it.

OP's original unit cell looks like

[image]

Now I could create a region using `DiscretizeGraphics` out of this,

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics@
  Normal@RegionPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 0.6, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5, 
     0.5}]
```

This gives an error message, but it works

[image]

I create a table of these regions,

```
regions = Table[
   TransformedRegion[region, TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]], {x, 
    2}, {y, 2}, {z, 2}];
```

and combine them into one `RegionPlot3D`

```
RegionPlot3D[regions, Mesh -> 10]
```

[image]

And simply by changing the `<` in the original code to a `>`, you can get the interstitial regions,

[image]

### Edit

Here is a method that I like better, since it doesn't give the error above, but it **is** a bit slower.   The unit cells and interstitial regions can be plotted via

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@
   RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{-.5, -.5, -.5}, {.5, .5, .5}], 
    Ball[{0, 0, 0}, Sqrt[.6]]];
regions = 
  Table[TransformedRegion[region, 
    TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]], {x, 2}, {y, 2}, {z, 2}];
RegionPlot3D[Flatten@regions, Mesh -> 10]
```

and

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@
   RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-.5, -.5, -.5}, {.5, .5, .5}], 
    Ball[{0, 0, 0}, Sqrt[.6]]];
regions = 
  Table[TransformedRegion[region, 
    TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]], {x, 2}, {y, 2}, {z, 2}];
RegionPlot3D[Flatten@regions, Mesh -> 10]
```

respectively.  I wish that `DiscretizeRegion` was not necessary, as that is what slows it down, but without it `RegionPlot3D` gives awful results.

Comment: Just tried it out. I think this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, welcome to the site, don't forget to take the [tour].

Comment: Additionally, is there any way to extract the complement of this structure? Meaning ... the periodic structure made up of the interstitial regions?

Comment: Yes, but it will take me a second, going to lunch now  :-)

Comment: Yes, sure. please take your time.

Comment: This is perfectly what I wanted. Thanks really!

Comment: If you want to avoid the error in your first approach add `Lighting -> None` in the `RegionPlot3D` graphics.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks, it's a bit confusing trying to make these region objects bahave how I want them to.

Comment: I know what you mean. Also, you don't need `Normal` when you add that `Option`, hence, making the code shorter.

Comment: @RunnyKine What? I thought I understood! `GraphicsComplex` means you have to use `Normal`, now I don't know what to believe....

Comment: Yeah, things keep changing all the time. The sweet world of *Mathematica* programming :)

Comment: Or maybe, `DiscretizeGraphics` handle both `Graphics` and `GraphicsComplex` objects automatically.

Comment: @RunnyKine I am moving to champaign soon, I get to peak under the covers and ask them what the heck is going on...

Comment: Well, congratulations! Hopefully, you'll be the one to help put an end to our frustrations on these new `Region` functions.

Comment: @RunnyKine I think they already have it all polished, but they are waiting on version 11. :-)

Comment: That's good to know. I'm guessing version 11 will be out this year?

Comment: @RunnyKine If I weren't on mobile I assume it would be telling me to move to chat.  I was joking a bit, it seems like they are just gonna move in decimal increments (it works for apple right?), but maybe they are going to bite the bullet and move up an integer.

Comment: Who knows, maybe they'll even skip an integer and go to 12, just like Microsoft did with Windows :)